# Why there is difference in ascii values of different compiler

Tags: c++, c

The code gives different outputs in gcc and in turbo c compiler.
Why there is difference between ascii values in these compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
int n=1;
while (n<70){
printf("Ascii value is %c\n",n);
n++;
}

return 0;
}
```

The above program gives different outputs for values,  say  from 1 - 16 or something like that in gcc and in turbo c.
Why is it so?

Comment: The first 32 "characters" are not actually printable, what will be printable will depend on environment. I recommend you check an [ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) to see which characters are actually printable. Or use the standard [`isprint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isprint) function.

Answer (score 7):

It's not the compiler, it's the console that displays those glyphs differently (the first 32 characters are non-printable). Glyphs 32 through 126 are guaranteed identical in all cases, though.

Comment: This. Turbo C runs on a DOS emulator so this is almost certainly about output encoding.

Comment: Yes, and it almost certainly is not ASCII. Run `chcp` to find out what the terminal is using. (@Paul, CP437 does have printable characters <32.)

Comment: Yes I've seen VGA characters and even `\n` has an associated glyph instead of being newline (it becomes newline later)

Comment: And characters below 32 are nonprintable. While the console does display them, it's their choice entirely on how to represent them.